# ServiceStack OrmLite - using String type for > and < expressions

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I have the following POCO class, where Date is defined as a string and will always conform to the following format 'yyyyMMdd'

```
public class Price {
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public string Date {get;set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
}
```

I would like to run a OrmLite query using Linq which retrieves all prices with a date greater or equal to a certain request string PriceDateGreaterThan parameter.

ie.

```
var prices = Db.Select<Price>().Where(ar => ar.PriceDate >= request.PriceDateGreaterThan).ToList();
```

Given PriceDate & PriceDateGreaterThan are both of type string (& not int or DateTime), how can I run this query using OrmLite?

Comment: If they’re both strings, the query would just be doing a string comparison. What’s the issue with the current query?

Comment: Operator '>=' cannot be applied to type 'string' and 'string'

Comment: here is sample code: https://gistlyn.com/?gist=840bc7f09292ad5753d07cef6063893e&collection=991db51e44674ad01d3d318b24cf0934

Comment: That link is the original Gistlyn gist, I think you forgot to press save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As .NET's BCL doesn't define comparison operators for `String` (e.g. `<=,<,>,=>`) you can't use a typed API for this so you'd need to use custom SQL, e.g:

```
var q = Db.From<Price>();
q.Where(q.Column<Price>(x => x.Date) + " >= {0}", priceDateGreaterThan);

var prices = db.Select(q);
```